# Ошибка при вычитании в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, арифметика, pic

я попытался написать код для вычитания(12-23)в ассемблере ,но видимо чего то не хватает и результат 245.Подскажите пожалуйста чего не хватает ?Заранее благодарен.
ПС.Я новичок в ассемблере .Прошу прошения если глупый вопрос.Но очень хочется разобраться.

```
      list p=16f877a
      #include <p16f877a.inc>
tempa EQU h'020'
tempb EQU h'021'

      org 0x00
      goto begin
      org 0x100

begin
      clrw
      clrf tempa
      clrf tempb
      movlw d'12'
      movwf tempa
      movlw d'23'
      movwf tempb
      subwf tempa,1
      nop
      end
```

Comment: Разность - отрицательна, вот Вы и получаете отрицательное значение в дополнительном коде. А интерпретировать его пытаетесь как беззнаковое.

Comment: @Akina А понял спасибо, а это можно считать полноценную программу которая вычитает или что то нужно добавить ? И вообще кто то можно увидеть результат(-11) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Все ты делаешь так.
- Все ты делаешь так. Просто `12 - 23 = -11` Отрицательное число.
- А как представляются отрицательные числа в памяти современных процов
  ? В виде дополнения до двух, а такое представление очень удобно
  потому что одна и та-же операция сложения или вычитания годится как
  для знаковых, так и для беззнаковых чисел. От этого процессор не
  знает знаковое число или беззнаковое. Различать их должен
  программист. `-11` знаковое в двоичном виде в байте будет хранится
  как `11110101` `245` беззнаковое в двоичном виде в байте будет
  хранится тоже как `11110101` Ты должен их различать и никто иной.

  Т.е. смотришь на `11110101` двоичное или что тоже самое `F5`
  шестнавдцатеричное и говоришь себе - я понимаю это число как знаковое
  и тогда оно `-11` или я понимаю это число как беззнаковое и тогда оно
  `245` А процик оба варианта не различает, он с обоими вариантами
  работает одними и теми-же операциями ADDWF SUBWF. А отладчик мысли
  твои читать не умеет и показывает это число как `245.` Но для тебя,
  если ты в своей проге понимаешь это число как знаковое оно `-11` и
  ничто иное.